# Let's paint the world with bacteria

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, atmosphere, engineering

**Some estimates put the percent of Earth's surface covered by landfills at 0.02%.**

Even if the world composted and recycled as much as possible, we would be left with an insanely large amount of waste to break down. We must find a way to deal with waste that cannot decompose in its current environment.

**In the very near future, using modern technology, the United Nations proposes the following solution:**

Using drones, helicopters, planes, and national militaries, a specific mixture will be spread across as many landfills as possible. If we can cover the Earth with waste in a matter of years, we can cover that waste with a thin layer of liquid in even less time. *This process will only be executed in all consenting countries; those skeptical of the procedure will not be obliged to participate.*

The mixture will contain (in order of decreasing abundance)

- **Water**
- **Moss (spores)** to break down solid waste
- **Fungi (spores)** to break down solid waste
- **Aerobic bacteria** to displace those using methane and make use of the increased oxygen from moss; to decompose organic matter faster
- ***[Ideonella sakaiensis](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6278/1196)*** to break down plastics with increased efficiency
- ***[Halomonas titanicae](http://Halomonas%20titanicae)*** to break down metals with increased efficiency

*Strains of bacteria may be farmed in vats in large facilities*

While some emmissions may result from this mixture, they are hypothesized to be overall less pollusive than the emissions that would result naturally. In a number of decades, this strategy is suggested to be able to reduce our landfills immensely.

### So can we actually "paint the world with bacteria" in this way?

Will the substance actually do the job (in a number of years)? If not, what would you change? Is anything in the mixture redundant or unnecessary?

Comment: If you think people don't like the UN now, wait until they spray metal eating bacteria on your car.

Comment: @kingledion The question addresses that. "*This process will only be executed in all consenting countries; those skeptical of the procedure will not be obliged to participate.*"

Comment: Hmmm....so you are saying you are going to spray aerosol bacteria on my neighbors property, and none of it will get to my property?

Comment: @kingledion My best answer is that landfills try to reduce the pollution of adjacent areas; perhaps it would just be applied to those with proven barriers in place. Still, that may be a reasonable point for an answer.

Comment: The fact that Ideonella sakaiensis can already metabolize PET plastic (soda-bottle plastic) is impressive, since that polymer was only invented in 1941.  IMHO evolution can move fast, when the selective pressure is high.  That said, lots of people are literally allergic to many fungal spores -- what happens if somebody (who may not even know they have this allergy) gets enough spores to go into anaphalactic shock??  IMHO, mass sprayings are something best approached with *extreme* caution, in case of dire need.

Comment: Is there a reason to presume these microorganisms are not already present where there is food for them?

Comment: @CortAmmon Yes. We know that aerobic bacteria are uncommon in landfills, but it has been suggested that we introduce them; we know that *Ideonella* simply have a small population; *Halomonas* needs a means to spread; and mosses and fungi simply need soil, which may be produced when the above bacteria kick in.

Comment: I don't understand why you would spread this out and then induce various "alien" life forms in an essentially uncontrolled manner (the bacteria might mutate and evolve to eat your car, the reinforcing rods in the concrete bridge and so on).

Comment: @Thucydides Perhaps native variants can be used for the mosses, fungi; as for the bacteria, they will potentially starve without food - a metal-eater has a hard time spreading across a concrete wall. After some decontamination or soil treatment for good measure there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Turning rubbish into reclaimed land isn't new nor is introducing bio-degradable products, so instead of leaving it to the "litter-bug" how about eliminating those "litter bugs" in the first place.

Comment: @user6760 See the question - even if we stop producing waste there will be old waste to take care of.

Comment: What I meant is there isn't a one size fits all solution, you can breed as many bacteria to your heart content the waste will just get replaced or finds new home. I wonder if I were to cover all the landfills with a mile thick of mucus(condominium for your bacterium) how long would it takes to remove 1% of the current waste?

Comment: You say "If we can cover the earth with waste in a matter of years" but the figure you quote is 0.02% of the earth's (land?) surface with landfill over the entire history of mankind. That's not "cover the earth with waste" and it's not "in a matter of years.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I do not say cover the whole earth; it may be easy to misinterpret how I wrote it but I assure you I understand the difference

Comment: @DavidRicherby the entire history is not the same of less than a century of large garbage dumps

Comment: @Zxyrra My point is hardly diminished by replacing "the entire history of mankind" with "the last 100 years."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some may consider 200,000 vs 100 years to be a large difference in the amount of waste.  Although if you have a cheaper alternative I'd be glad to hear it in the answer section

Comment: @Zxyrra Do the math. If it has taken 100 years to cover 0.02% of the earth's surface, it will take 499,900 years to cover the rest. That is a lot more than "a matter of years". That is a matter of two and a half times the figure that you just quoted as the entire history of mankind.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not arguing that we'll cover the entire surface of the earth, I'm arguing that we need to clean up 0.02% that is already polluted, and asking if my solution works. Please reread the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Landfills which are properly built are designed to isolate wastes from the surrounding environment, essentially forever. As an interesting note, there is an exhibit in Toronto's "Ontario Science Museum" where a core sample from a landfill is on display in a sealed tube. The exhibition note suggests the material in the tube is decomposing *faster* than the material still in the landfill.

I don't understand why you would spread this out and then induce various "alien" life forms in an essentially uncontrolled manner (the bacteria might mutate and evolve to eat your car, the reinforcing rods in the concrete bridge and so on).

If the goal is to reduce or eliminate landfills, then the proper response would be to build controlled industrial process sites where waste can be excavated sorted and then placed in reactors to be quickly and efficiently broken down, under ideal circumstances and with control over what does in and what goes out. The bacteria are being fed a concentrated diet of their favourite materials and nothing more, the temperature, humidity, ph balance and whatever other factors they need are controlled closely and the bacteria are under close observation to ensure mutant strains are not arising (the entire vat would be killed and then a new batch of "clean" bacteria is induced to carry on the reduction).

Of course even this is wasteful, since the metals, plastics and so on could probably be more profitably recycled into new products or raw materials. Undifferentiated waste could also be fed into a [plasma reactor](https://www.wired.com/2012/01/ff_trashblaster/) and solids turned into glass, while organics would become converted into Syngas to power the site and provide electrical energy to export to nearby cities and so on.

This plan could even be instituted by private corporations seeing a profit opportunity if the costs of excavation and waste sorting and recycling or plasma reduction are low enough.

Comment: While I agree that there may be control issues present, **economics must be taken into account**. Collecting all the waste, building giant, effective incinerators, and storing the resulting emissions costs much, much more than culturing bacteria in one or two locations and then flying drones.

Comment: If control issues do arise, those areas can be isolated, and soil can be dealt with by existing waste treatment plants.

Comment: @Zxyrra isolating existing landfill might turn out more expensive than building bioreactors.

Comment: @Mołot Even if isolating landfill costs more (which is a different discussion) how many tons must be shoveled into reactors - vs applying the substance without moving the waste itself?

Comment: @Zxyrra the same amount. You'd have to mix landfill to get any significant effect... Or, if your bacteria can eat metal and plastic, you need to empty the landfill, change lining to something it can't eat, and fill it again. So, umm... Seems reactors may need only ½ of the showeling.

Comment: @Mołot landfill barriers will decay eventually anyways - they are not sustainable. I see no problem in eating through them if you're releasing degraded waste as opposed to less degraded without the process of spraying

Comment: You don't see a problem with metal eating bacteria in water, in contact with water pipes (mostly metal), bridges (metal, or metal-reinforced concrete), ships (again, metal hulls)? Really?

Comment: How is it more economical to dig up a landfill, drive trucks or trains to spread material around, then spray bacteria in an uncontrolled environment to consume the wastes? Landfills are essentially bodies of very concentrated "ores", so mining the "ore" and dropping it into a reactor or plasma torch right away is far more efficient and controllable.